SPLG vs VOO vs Split in between?
For my IRA, I'm dumping money into it every year hoping to get a big number many years later when I retire, so I certainly want a 99.99% reliable option.
Many recommend VOO, but it seems that SPLG has lower fees and possibly a slightly higher return. I also haven't found obvious negatives about SPLG, but it just feels that SPLG is a bit more niche?
I think for compounding to work best, I'd need to commit all my funds to one place, so I'm not sure how good splitting between voo and splg is. Since I can only choose one, I want to make sure that I'm committing to the most reliable option.

What do you mean by "99.99% reliable"? If you're talking about guaranteed returns, the only "reliable" options are US Treasury Bonds - everything else carries risk of loss or default. VOO and SPLG are virtually identical, but their returns are not guaranteed. You'll have periods where they go up and periods when they go down.

FYI - splitting investments has no effect on compounding.

SPLG and VOO both track the S&P 500. The difference in expenses is 0.01%.
They are both ETFs, track the same index, and have essentially the same expenses. It doesn't really matter which one you choose. We're talking an extremely small difference between the two.

When you have doubts such as you've expressed, it can be useful to graph the long term performance of the candidates on the same graph. This is a graph of SPLG in red and VOO in blue taken from StockCharts.com from January 2015 through today with all dividends reinvested.

As you can see, together they make one trace with brief fringes of red or blue, meaning a slight divergence for a short time, but no discernible difference over the long term.
This also means that you can split your investment between these funds 50-50 or in any proportion you wish, or just pick one of them. It doesn't matter in the long run, except that splitting your investment can offer some protection from a management error that affects only one of the funds. So compounding, as you call it, or dividend reinvestment, will work equally well with a single fund or with both funds.

While they are essentially equivalent as investments, it may be beneficial for investors with small amounts of money to choose SPLG over VOO because its lower price per share (roughly one eighth) allows for investing smaller amounts of money. This isn't likely to matter to an investor with even a few thousand dollars, but it is helpful when investing only a few hundred.

No investment is 99.9% secure. The first question is how old are you?  20's or 30's? Invest in riskier funds. 50's 60's invest in more secure funds.

The old SWAG approach was "invest (your age)% in something safer like bonds; invest the rest in higher risk/higher reward equities like stocks (or these days stock index funds)." Adjust and add detail to fit your risk tolerance and willingness to work more to try to improve results. More detail in past answers.
